# How to Insert values into one table from all tables from database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, alter

I have problems with the last line of the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['kolona']))
{
foreach($_POST['kolona'] as $vrednost)
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tablica ADD $vrednost text NOT NULL");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablica ( ".(implode(',',($_POST['kolona']))).") SELECT ".(implode(',',($_POST['kolona'])))." FROM druga");
}
```

First query is making columns in table 'tablica' and second query suppose to insert values in that columns from all tables from which are the columns, for now it's just hard coded, it's only from table 'druga', but i don't know how to go through the all tables, not just 'druga'. I tried with a loop and also with implode function but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: Yea, I hear you, definitely next time, I am so stuck on this problem that I didn't even thought of that this time.

Comment: This code will never work. if the `kolona` array contains multiple values, you'll alter the table and create a field for the FIRST value encountered, but then try to insert ALL of the other values at the same time, even though their fields haven't been created yet. Any design which calls for such dynamic table/field creation is a BAD design.

Comment: Ok, damn, do you have any suggestion? What would be better solution? I have like list of all the names of the tables on the screen with names of the columns in the checkboxes-that's array $_POST['kolone'], and than i need to put all the checked columns in one new table in db

Comment: @iva Looks like a job for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` so long as you have a consistent `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Comment: Hm, ok, I don't know how to do that yet, but I try to figure it out. Tnx @tadman

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle merging problems like this using the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature:

```
INSERT INTO target (id, column1, column2)
  SELECT id, column1, column2 FROM source
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1=VALUES(column1), column2=VALUES(column2)
```

It works well provided you have a `PRIMARY KEY` column without conflicts between your source and target tables.

Comment: It's not working, my table called 'tablica' is empty, it has only id column, and after this query that you gave me still stays empty :/

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors? What does your `SELECT` statement return when run in isolation?

Comment: no, no errors, i hard coded also, columns and everything, so i don't have any errors but nothing happens, this is my first script actually, so I don't know yet what is running in isolation

Comment: By "isolation" I mean run only the `SELECT` statement, which in this example is the `SELECT id, column1, column2 FROM source` part. If this does not return any rows, the `INSERT` one won't insert any data.

Comment: yea, yea i just figure it out, that running in isolation, stupid of me, i tried it, still nothing. Insert is not working apparently, don't know why.

Comment: So your `SELECT` is not returning any rows?

Comment: Ok, sorry, just INSERT INTO..SELECT works, but still everything is hard coded, again i named from which table i am taking columns, and I need to be from every table from the base.